# how to configure unit test in vscode for python unittest

Tags: python-3.6, python-unittest, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I am using Python 3.6 and latest version of vscode.

My folder structure:

```
/folder
    /src
        src.py
    /tests
        src_test.py
```

src.py:

```
class Addition:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  def run(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

src_test.py:

```
import unittest

from ..src.addition import Addition

class TestAddition(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_addition(self):
    inst = Addition(5, 10)
    res = inst.run()
    self.assertEqual(res, 16)

if( __name__ == "main"):
  unittest.main()
```

here is my project settings.json:

```
{
  "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    ".",
    "-p",
    "*_test.py"
  ],
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

Then under project root folder:

> python3 -m unittest tests/src_test.py

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.src_test'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an `__init__.py` file under the tests folder, and the import your module needs a tweak.

The `__init__.py` allows Python to go up in the folder structure and reach the `src.py` module (another `__init__.py` under src would be nice, but it is not necessary to make the vscode tests work).

This is a working folder structure:

```
.
├── src
│   └── src.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── src_test.py
```

Also, change the line in src.py:

- (OLD) `from ..src.addition import Addition`
- (NEW) `from src.src import Addition`

Comment: I did just that. However, I have the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model' . . . I perform the import like this: from src.package.myclass import MyClass

Comment: Do you know what it can be? I use pipenv to manage my project in the vscode.